# Use case for String split

Tags: regex, split, apache-stringutils

I want code snippet for splitting the below string:

Input : `select * from table where a=? and b=? and c=?`

```
Output: 
    Str1: select * from table where a=?
    Str2: and b=? 
    Str3: and c=?
```

I do not want to use indexof as of now, whether **StringUtils** or regex can help me here? I was looking for StringUtilus but I did not get anything in it. Your input is appreciated.

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice:

```
inputStr.split("(?=\band\b)")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying it in php then try ,

```
$myvar = explode('and','select * from table where a=? and b=? and c=? ');
$str1 = $myvar[0];
$str2 = $myvar[1];
$str3 = $myvar[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

I got, we can use

```
    String str = "select * from table where a=? and b=? anc c=?";
    String[] tokens = str.split("\\?");

    for (String string : tokens) {
        System.out.print("tokens: "+string);
    }
```